# Proving that $f(x) = (x + 1) / (x^2 - 1)$ does not have a limit at $1$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove that the function 
$f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = (x+1)/(x^2-1)$ does not have a limit at $1$ through an epsilon-delta proof. So far, I have attempted to prove this by assuming the function has a limit, L, at 1. I just can't seem to arrive at a contradiction. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Well, this is $f(x) = 1 / (x - 1)$, so it should be pretty obvious why it doesn't approach any number $L$, because it outgrows $L$. Formalize this.

Comment: Hm, some people might argue that it does, and it is $+\infty$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The limits from the right and left are not equal.  The limit does not exist.  ;-))

Comment: @T.Bongers Tyler, the reason that the limit fails to exist is that the limits from the right and left are not equal ($+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively).   ;-)) -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Given the way the question was phrased, I assume that they mean "as a real number" (especially since the domain is restricted to only include the left approach).

Comment: @T.Bongers I see your point.  If one looks at the title of the question, one might infer differently.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Note that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1}{x-1}=-\infty$ since for any $B<0$, $\frac{1}{x-1}<B$ whenever $1+\frac1B <x<1$.

Now, apply analogous logic to the right-sided limit and show that the limits are not equal.

Comment: Who down voted this?